# Factorial solve without substitution

Tags: factorial

I'm in stuck with this dimostration. I've got $$\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}$$ and it's must be $$\frac{1}{n+1}$$
If I put n=3, I've got $$\frac{3!}{(3+1)!}=\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{3+1}$$ and it's correct. But I can't prove the resolution without replacing, like in this case that I put n=3.
Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Please fix the typesetting.

Comment: How do you define the factorial ?

Comment: What Yves means, is that you can use the definition of factorial (plug it in the expression) and you should be able to proceed.

Comment: The definition is n! =n(n-1)!  And n! /(n-k)! =n(n-1)(n-k+1)

Comment: Literally the first thing you wrote, yields the result.

Comment: 3(3-1)!/4!=3*2!/4!=3*2*1/4*3*2*1=1/4 but without number I can't. It's something like n(n-1)!/(n+1)!= and I don't know how to preceded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of factorial, $n! = 1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times n$. So we have $(n+1)! = 1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times n \times (n+1) = n! \times (n+1)$. But from $n! \times (n+1) = (n+1)!$ we simply rearrange to get the desired result.

Comment: Ok maybe I solved it. n! =n!(n-1) and (n+1)!=n!(n-1)(n+1). I simplify the in fraction n!(n-1). And the rest is 1/(n+1). Is it correct?

Comment: Almost, you should get n! = n! and (n+1)! = n!(n+1), and cancel out n! inside the fraction